# Using AudioKit to plot Waveform of samplefile in UIView

Tags: ios, swift, waveform, audiokit

I'm making my first steps in Swift and AudioKit. I played little bit with the playgrounds. Now I'm trying to draw a waveform of a sample in a UIView.

My code didn't work. The UIView stay blank.

```
@IBOutlet weak var audioOutputPlot: EZAudioPlot!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let file = try! AKAudioFile(readFileName: "Sounds/drumloop_1.wav")
    let player = try! AKAudioPlayer(file: file)
    let plot = AKNodeOutputPlot(player, frame: audioOutputPlot.bounds)
    plot.plotType = .buffer
    plot.shouldFill = true
    plot.shouldMirror = true
    plot.color = UIColor.blue

    audioOutputPlot.addSubview(plot)

}
```

I have connected the @IBOutlet audioOutputPlot with the UIView with the Interface Builder and have wrote "EZAudioPlot" in the Custom Class of it.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm thinking that you've locally declared file, player, and plot from within your viewDidLoad and these are being forgotten.